# Animate translationY Sticky Header

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i am using [this](https://github.com/timehop/sticky-headers-recyclerview) library for sticky headers in recycler view

> now i have to animate header view with transalationY to a specific length

and I am using

> `View headerView =headersDecor.getHeaderView(trendingListView,firstVisibleItem);
>           if (headerView!=null){
>               headerView.animate().translationY(1000);
>           }`
>
> but the header is not moving ...please suggest me what i am doing wrong ? and what should be most appropriate way of doing this